# Trying to update a record, but the update code only updates one of the timestamp fields and nothing else

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a database table that I need to update records on. The code to add a new record works just fine, But when I go to update an existing record, not all the fields update with the new information in the form.

Here's the code:

```
    private void updateExistingDSN()
    {
        //Update existing DSN
        try
        {
            using (PathFinderDataContext pfdcContext = new PathFinderDataContext())
            {
                DSN oldDSN = pfdcContext.DSNs.Single(dsn => dsn.DSNID == int.Parse(Request["dsn"]));

                oldDSN.Auth_AuthorizationID = int.Parse(Request["auth"]);
                oldDSN.ServiceProvided_ServiceProvidedID = int.Parse(Request["sp"]);
                oldDSN.EvidenceBPMU = short.Parse(ddlEvidenceBPMU.SelectedValue);
                oldDSN.LocationOfVisit = txtLocationOfVisit.Text;
                oldDSN.ChildrenPresent = txtNamesOfChildrenPresent.Text;
                oldDSN.ParentPresent = txtNamesOfParentsPresent.Text;
                oldDSN.OthersPresent = txtNamesOfOthersPresent.Text;
                oldDSN.DescribeGoals = txtDescribeGoals.Text;
                oldDSN.DescribeStrategy = txtDescribeStrategies.Text;
                oldDSN.DescibeParentingSkills = txtDescribeParentingSkills.Text;
                oldDSN.DescribeSafetyConcerns = txtDescribeSafetyConcerns.Text;
                oldDSN.OtherInfo = txtOtherInfo.Text;
                oldDSN.Schedule_Monday = float.Parse(txtMonday.Text);
                oldDSN.Schedule_Tuesday = float.Parse(txtTuesday.Text);
                oldDSN.Schedule_Wednesday = float.Parse(txtWednesday.Text);
                oldDSN.Schedule_Thursday = float.Parse(txtThursday.Text);
                oldDSN.Schedule_Friday = float.Parse(txtFriday.Text);
                oldDSN.Schedule_Saturday = float.Parse(txtSaturday.Text);
                oldDSN.Schedule_Sunday = float.Parse(txtSunday.Text);
                oldDSN.DateSaved = DateTime.Now;
                oldDSN.SavedBy_UserID = currentEmployee.EmployeeID;
                pfdcContext.SubmitChanges();
            }

            Response.Redirect("~/pages/updateTimesheet.aspx?action=update&ProvidedServiceId=" + int.Parse(Request["sp"]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage.Text = "<b>Error updating an existing DSN record!</b><br /><br />" + ex.ToString();
            warnings.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The only field that updates is oldDSN.DateSaved, everything else just stays the same. No errors or exceptions thrown or anything. Acts like it works, but doesn't. Also, when I hardcode values to be updated, the record updates just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Debug your code and check whether there are values you wish to update or not.

Comment: If you are using visual studio, try setting a breakpoint at the top of the method and right click -> watch oldDSN.  Check that all of the values are being correctly updated.  There's no way I can say this inoffensively: because the only value being updated is the one that is not generated by your code (DateTime.Now), I get the feeling that most likely it is your code that is generating the incorrect values.

Comment: I'm stepping through the code right now. It'll be just a minute and I'll update and let you know whats going on.

Comment: Okay, what's happening is: The code appears to be working just fine, however when it grabs the text from the HTML elements (text boxes, etc), it doesn't grab the newly typed information, it grabs what was put in the text box when page_load ran, which was, of course, the old values, therefore making it look like its not updating them... I'm confused as to why it wouldn't grab the information that was just typed in them, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Page_Load` (where you put the information from your datasource into the TextBoxes, etc) you need to wrap the databinding code in a `If(Page.IsPostBack)` block.

So your code should look something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Whatever you use to load the data from the database into 
        // your server controls goes here
        loadData(); // example
    }
}
```

This is why you're not getting the updated information - your markup elements are being reloaded from the database before your Update code has a chance to run.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been stuck here for a day or two at work, and couldn't figure it out. Spent a long time looking at my update code, and didn't even think to look at this part of my code. Thanks again!